# Can a website detect which method you are using to connect (LL2P, SSTP and PPTP)

Tags: encryption, network, vpn, pptp

When you connect to a website using a VPN with the same IP however using a different type of connection each time (LL2P, SSTP and PPTP) can the website detect the difference between these connection.

For example lets say you connect using an SSTP connection the first time but the next time you decide to use an LL2P connect. Is the website able to detect that you've used another method to connect to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They cannot infer it from the technical analysis of their communication with you. All they see is TCP datagrams in IP packets, their characteristics shouldn't be impacted too much by your mode of connection (the MTU of the connection might be, but that's a pretty weak correlation).

Answer (score 0):

The site cannot tell directly by looking at your communication channel as they will always see the same connection from the VPN provider so [TCP fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) will not work. But if the site was very determined and had many data points to correlate, they *may* be able to notice some differences in your connections and create [fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) for the different connections. Perhaps changes in response time, MTU (as suggested by @Bruno Rohée), and other subtle differences. In short, it may be possible, but it is extremely unlikely.